# Keep Excel formatting when copying content to a text editor

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting

I have an Excel file with a column of codes which indicate parent-child relationships with some kind of formatting:

[image: Codes]

The indent is controlled with "Indent Level" option on "Left (Indent)". Copying and pasting to a text editor doesn't keep spacing.

I'd like to be able to copy and paste spacing to a text editor. Can I somehow make the formatting explicit - add a column that indicates the indent level or anything similar to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with the built-in features of Excel, however you can create an Excel macro to do this:

```
Sub CopyCellValuesWithIndent()

    Dim rSelection As Range, c As Range
    Dim lIndent As Long, i As Long
    Dim sCopyString As String
    Dim DataObj As Object

    'LATE BIND THE "MSForms.DataObject" LIBRARY TO USE THE CLIPBOARD
    Set DataObj = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    Set rSelection = Selection

    For Each c In rSelection.Cells

        lIndent = c.IndentLevel

        'ADD INDENT
        If lIndent > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To lIndent

                sCopyString = sCopyString & vbTab

            Next i
        End If

        sCopyString = sCopyString & c.Value & vbCrLf

    Next c

    sCopyString = Left(sCopyString, InStrRev(sCopyString, vbCrLf))

    DataObj.SetText sCopyString
    DataObj.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

Open your VBA Editor (Alt+F11), create a new module and paste in the code above.  After which, select the cells containing the values you want to copy (with indent) and after running this macro simply use the paste option in your text editor to retain the indent levels.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to avoid VBA you could try this. This is my preferred method - I simply set column widths to be very narrow (eg 10px).

[image: nested rows]

You can switch off gridlines, or set borders to make it look nicer.

[image: nested rows without gridlines]

If your data includes numbers (as your sample data does), you'll need to convert them all to text by adding a `'` (apostrophe) to signal text data - otherwise the full content will not appear and you'll just get `#`.

If you do this you'll get these green tags saying you have an error. Select all, right-click and say ignore errors.

[image: ignore errors]

When you copy to your text editor, the indents will be there as tabs.

[image: tabs in notepad]

Comment: +1 for the non-VBA solution.  Note that it is not necessary to use an `'` (apostrophe) to store numbers as text (thus retaining leading zeros) if you simply change the cell number format to `Text` prior to entering the value.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work for me. I'm on Excel 2010. If you find you don't need to do that then great :) one less step!